# In kotlin, how do I mock a suspend function that wraps a callback?

Tags: callback, kotlin, mocking, mockito, kotlinx.coroutines

Let's say there's an interface with a callback:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    fun doSomething(arg: String, callback: (Exception?, Long) -> Unit)
}
```

which I extend into a suspend function like this:

```
suspend fun SomeInterface.doSomething(arg: String): Long = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    this.doSomething(arg) { err, result ->
        if (err == null) {
            cont.resume(result)
        } else {
            cont.resumeWithException(err)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to mock this in tests, but am failing.
Ideally I'd like to use something like this:

```
@Test
fun checkService() {
    runBlocking {
        val myService = mock<SomeInterface>()
        whenever(myService.doSomething(anyString())).thenReturn(1234L)
        val result = myService.doSomething("")
        assertEquals(result, 1234L)
    }
}
```

The above syntax fails with a mockito exception because it's expecting a matcher for the callback.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

How can I mock a suspend function like that?
If a similar syntax is not possible how can I have the mock call back with the desired arguments such that the suspend variant that is used throughout my code returns the desired result during tests?

**Update**:
It seems it's not possible when it's an extension function. Based on [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik)'s comment, I gather it's because an extension is simply a static function which is out of mockito's capability.

When the suspend function is a member function, then it works as expected, with my original syntax.

Here is a gist with some demo code:
https://gist.github.com/mirceanis/716bf019a47826564fa57a77065f2335

Comment: It's not actually expecting a matcher for the callback, but for the implicit continuation parameter all `suspend fun`s declare at the class file level. Try providing it with an empty `Continuation`.

Comment: `whenever(myService.doSomething(anyString(), any(Continuation.class))`

Comment: That doesn't compile, nor does `any<Continuation<Long>>()`.
Also, if I use `any()` for the second param, then the `.thenReturn(1234L)` doesn't work since it's expecting `Unit`, not `Long`

If I add a second param there, I'm basically mocking the original interface call, not the suspend function.

Comment: I don't mind mocking the original as long as the suspend variant works and responds with what I want during tests. I just don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Ah yes, it slipped my mind. The extension fun is actually a `public static` Java method in the compiled class. You won't be able to mock it. However, there are ways to mock the original with more complexity than just `thenReturn`.

Comment: [Here](https://fernandocejas.com/2014/04/08/unit-testing-asynchronous-methods-with-mockito/), this post shows you the relevant Mockito syntax. It's `doAnswer(Answer).when(...)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suggest using [MockK](https://mockk.io/) for your tests, which is more coroutine-friendly.

To mock a coroutine, you can use `coEvery` and `returns` like below:

```
val interf = mockk<SomeInterface>()
coEvery { a.doSomething(any()) } returns Outcome.OK
```

Comment: Mockk does not support generic at all.
If I have a method that return Result<SomeClass> it is not possible to mock it at all

Answer (score 23):

When you need to

> on .... do return ..

and method is suspended, with **mockito** you can use this:

- use this lib [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin)
- Mock your object, lets name it myObject (myObject has suspend method named isFoo)

then:

```
 myObject.stub {
    onBlocking { isFoo() }.doReturn(true)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have doReturn execute suspend funcs before it returns?